# how to order with parentID and ordermenu

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i have menu table with Following characteristics:

tblMenu: *ID*, *Title*, *ParentID*, *OrderM*

i want select menu and order with ParentID and OrderM as follows:

EX:

data in table:

```
ID = 1  Title = menu1 ParentID = 0 OrderM = 1
ID = 2  Title = menu2 ParentID = 0 OrderM = 2
ID = 3  Title = menu3 ParentID = 0 OrderM = 3
ID = 4  Title = submenu2-1 ParentID = 2 OrderM = 1
ID = 5  Title = submenu2-2 ParentID = 2 OrderM = 2
ID = 6  Title = submenu1-2 ParentID = 1 OrderM = 2
ID = 7  Title = submenu1-1 ParentID = 1 OrderM = 1
```

I want the following result with select LINQ:

```
menu1
submenu1-1
submenu1-2
menu2
submenu2-1
submenu2-2
menu3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work ([Sample](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40318759/linqpad3.png)):

```
var result =
  l.Where(c => c.ParentID == 0)
   .Select(c => new {Menu = c, Sub = l.Where(ci => ci.ParentID == c.ID).OrderBy(s => s.OrderM)})
   .OrderBy(ao => ao.Menu.OrderM)
   .SelectMany(ao => ao.Sub.Count() == 0 ? new List<C> {ao.Menu} : new List<C> {ao.Menu}.Concat(ao.Sub));
```

Comment: Working with nested submenus is definitely possible, but some improvements to query are needed.

Comment: its working for menu1, submenu1-1, submenu1-1-1 ,...? (nested submenus)

Comment: No, it doesn't. Actually, Linq doesn't work well with a recursion. Even if you can restrict your nesting depth, still linq query'll be overcomplicated. You may consider imperative solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the ordering that you're having trouble with, try using OrderBy and ThenBy to achieve the order that you require.

For example:

```
 var items = source.OrderBy(i => i.OrderM).ThenBy(o => o.ParentID);
```

Comment: It's hard to see from your question what you're trying to achieve specifically.  At first glance it looks like you want to order the records in a specific manner.  Could you please add a little more explanation?

Comment: I want all the sub-menus are your menu

Comment: In that case check out aush's answer